# Can a U.K. worker work remotely in France for one month for a U.K. company?

Tags: united-kingdom, telecommute, remote-work

I’m a U.K. resident working for a U.K. company. The company is based in Manchester but I work remotely in the south. I have a love for French culture and have lots of French friends (through previously learning the language) and I would like to spend some time there but don’t have the available holiday days available.

Is it legal for me to travel to France and work remotely for a month for my U.K. company? Would there be any additional costs or paperwork for my company?

Comment: Your tax address changes if you are found to live more than 6 months per year in France. AFAIK.
The money transactions are all happening in between UK banks, so there isn't even any change in your banking address. If your working address changes, anything under 6 months is holiday work. As a frenchman i tell you: be wary about declaring anything small to French admins... They will have you filling in 20 pages for changing a skylight on your roof, including an architetural assessment of your new skylight, they will send you 400 pages of junk mail if you register a new company in France (insuran

Answer (score 5):

It should be fine, especially if it’s remote work ie you’re connecting via Remote Desktop or something. Even working “for” the company but offline on your laptop is fine.
It won’t affect your tax status for either country; you’re not there long enough.
Up until Dec 2016, I spent nearly 5 years doing this between UK and Spain.

The only issues the company might have are:

- costs (do they have to pay your expenses? there are no paperwork or related costs),
- trust - although that should be ok, and
- availability. It would help reassure them if you’re fairly near a major airport with direct flights. I know from experience that it might be quicker to get to Manchester from abroad than driving from UK south coast (4/5 hours).

Comment: @seventyeightist, thanks for neatening up the answer text for me; much appreciated. I find it really hard if I'm trying to contribute from my phone screen.

Answer (score -2):

First you need to make sure that your company allows you to work abroad, which may mean that company information might be more accessible to foreign authorities. At my last job for a UK company, EU countries, especially more trustworthy ones would have been Ok but requiring company permission, South Korea would have been likely a "No" and North Korea an absolute "No".

Since you say UK *resident* - with pre-settled status you want to make sure that you are over six months of every 12 month period in the UK, or you might have trouble getting settled status. With settled status I can't remember if you can leave unlimited, or for five years, but nothing to worry about there.

Taxes... Well, you have two choices. You tell authorities that you work in France, or you don't. Not telling them is not quite legal, but makes life a lot easier because your company just continues paying you as they do now, and you won't need a visa. Yes, you are legally working in the place where your bum hits the chair, in your case that would be France. So you'd need a visa etc. etc. There may be a limit, maybe up to three months, where you don't need one.

Sorry, I forgot: If you are not a UK *citizen* but an EU citizen, that makes moving a lot easier, because you are free to move to any country in the EU and work there, but taxes would still be a problem if the authorities know.

Comment: The question dates from 2019, the situation has changed significantly in the mean time - I'm not sure it's helpful to answer now.

Comment: @JoeStevens - People read the question now. If you can point out any mistakes instead of "I'm not sure" please tell me. And please point out how the question is affected by changes. It isn't. Answers are.

Comment: @JoeStevens Perhaps the fact that the situation has changed significantly means that a more up-to-date answer would actually be of use. Either that or delete the question?

Comment: @gnasher729 OK, I would argue the situation has changed so significantly due to the end of the Brexit transition period at the end of 2020 that this has ceased to be a Workplace topic and would now be a legal question.

Comment: I would argue that is nonsense. Especially for a non-citizen, there is very little changed.

Comment: The siutation hsa changed from "sure, hop on a Eurostar" to an extensive discussion of visa requirements. I don't think this belongs on this site.

Comment: For a citizen. I can just hop on a Eurostar. Same as in 2019. And in a few years, I can just hop on a Eurostar back.